# google sheet Query change dd/mm/yy to dd mmm yyyy

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have booking forms filled in from a google form, results end up in a google sheet.
in the third column of the google sheet (C), I have dates that come in dd/mm/yy format.
to import them into mailchimp, I need them to be in dd mmm yyyy format.

I have tried copying the date column with Query but don't manage to get the output in the right format.
How can I combine
`=QUERY(A1:K, "SELECT C", 1)`
= gives me the same date in the same format in a separate column
and
`=TEXT(C2, "dd mmm yyyy")` = gives me the appropriate result but cannot be copied automatically to future lines created by googleform.

I want them to automatically populate a new column with dates in this format:20 Dec 2020

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why not format your column will do??

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY(A1:K, "select C format C 'dd mmm yyyy'", 1)
```

or:

```
=INDEX(TEXT(C2:C, "dd mmm yyyy"))
```